# How to make a WebBrowser control auto adjust its height in Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, height, webbrowser-control

**Context**
I create a WebBrowser control in the xaml, and bind some html via string to it, let it to display them in HTML way. The project is based on Windows Phone OS 7.1

**What I Found**
Everything works fine, but with one problem. Unless I define the height in the XAML, the WebBrowser will never auto adjust its height. That means when I don't define its height, it even has 0 height and hide itself. so how can I make it?

**What I want the WebBrowser to be**
1 - auto adjust its height via the passing HTML string
2 - no scrollbar because the WebBrowser already stretch its height to fit the content

```
        <phone:WebBrowser FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          wb:WebBrowserHtmlBinding.HtmlString="{Binding MainFloor}"
                          Margin="12" 
                          Foreground="{StaticResource TitleColor}"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Are you building for 7.0 or 7.1? 7.0 supports IE7 tech, 7.1 takes you to IE9 tech, which for some content will load fine in the device browser but not in the webbrowser control. I would try a build to 7.1 to test that possibility.

Comment: I just tested and it works here. What is the container of the WebBrowser control?

Comment: @OlivierPayen StackPanel

Comment: @ChrisW. The project is based on Windows Phone OS 7.1

Comment: Hi @AlbertGao.. Did you find the answer for this question. Now I need this same solution. Please let me know.. Thanks in advance..